# Overriding a column in one excel file with data from a separate excel file

Tags: excel, hashmap, apache-poi

I would like to read data from one excel file and override the data in a second excel file with the first excel file using Java & Apache-POI.

I am a beginner in java developing with no hashmap experience, but after doing research I believe this is the method I need to go about. I have been stuck finding a clear solution though on where to begin.

Comment: Please supply a better your requirement. Do you need to override a portion of these files? Or the whole file? What do you need at the end?

Comment: I need to store the data from the first excel file into a hashmap, compare it to similar data in a second excel file and if the data is different I need to replace the data to match the first file.

Comment: Why don't you skip check process and rewrite directly new data?

Comment: Could you provide more help with doing that? I am fairly new to java and apache poi so I am unsure of going about doing so.

Comment: if you are generating both the files you could compare them with an hash function so you can skip their parsing to save time. then if their hashes differ you can start writing new one. or better, instead of rewriting new one you could simply delete the first and rename the second one